# I need to get current active word document name using late binding in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using create object but can I get active document name using create object. I am doing late bindings because incompatibility with word versions.

Here is my code:

```
Dim app as Object 
Set app = createobject("Word.Application") 
Dim wrddoc as Object 
Set wrddoc = app.ActiveDocument
```

Comment: If you use `createobject("Word.Application")` it creates a new instance of Word (without any document in it). Therefore you cannot access the `ActiveDocument` because there is no document unless you create one in that instance of Word. Either add a new document `Set wrddoc = app.documents.Add` or use [GetObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function) to catch a already existing Word instance (instead of creating a new one).

Comment: From comment in deleted answer: _But when I am using getobject it is showing missing references_.  Remove any references you have set to Word as that is early binding and will muck up when versions aren't compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, just because we create an instance of Word it doesn't mean there are any Word documents in our Word Application. This is something we have to explicitly do in VBA when we work with different Office Applications.

You were close, but you were missing a line of code:

```
'Declare your variables
Dim WrdApp as Object
Dim WrdDoc as Object  

'Create an instance of Word, and make it visible.
Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    WrdApp.Visible

'Create a document in the word application, by default this will be the active document.
Set WrdDoc = app.Documents.Add
```